# How do I optimize this stored procedure to improve speed of fetching data?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, query-optimization, ssms

Below is the stored procedure I am referring to.

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_GetReportDetails] ******/
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[usp_GetReportDetails]', N'P') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetReportDetails]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

/*
Description : This is an SP for SSRS report dataset.
> Fetch the report details based on input filters, the input filters are multivalued-parameters (string with comma-separated values)
> Requirement is to fetch all the details for each project as a record in the output list
*/

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].usp_GetReportDetails 
(
    @sponsorg nvarchar(200), 
    @programname nvarchar(200), 
    @portfolio nvarchar(200), 
    @executingdep nvarchar(200), 
    @requestingdep nvarchar(200), 
    @projectmanager nvarchar(200)
)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

declare @fy int=dbo.fnc_FiscalYear(getdate());

--PART:1
--First I am fetching the latest QPID(An ID which identifies Forecast records) for each project ID.
create table #pidQpidList(qpid int,type nvarchar(50),ProjectID int,ProjectCode nvarchar(max),ProjectName nvarchar(max))
insert into #pidQpidList
select qpid, type, ProjectID,ProjectCode,ProjectName from
   ( select E.qpid, e.Type,e.ProjectID,PM.ProjectCode,PM.ProjectName,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY e.Type,e.projectid,e.fiscalyear ORDER BY w.date desc) as rn
FROM AmtrakQTYPLANExtension E  
    JOIN PROJECTProjectMain PM on PM.ProjectId=E.ProjectID AND PM.IsActive=1 
    left join LibraryExecutingDepartment led on led.ID=PM.ExecutingDepartment
    left join LIBRARYProjectOrganization lpo on lpo.id=led.OrganizationID
    AND (@Portfolio = '0' OR PM.ProjectId in (select * from fnGetProjectIdbyPortfolio(@Portfolio)))
    AND (@programname = '' OR ISNULL(PM.ProjectClass,0) IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT((@programname), ',')))
    AND (@executingdep = '' OR ISNULL(lpo.id,0) IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT((@executingdep), ',')))
    AND (@requestingdep = '' OR ISNULL(PM.RequestingDepartmentID,0) IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT((@requestingdep), ',')))
    AND (@projectmanager = '' OR ISNULL(PM.ProjectManager,0) IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT((@projectmanager), ','))) 
   JOIN BDGTESTBudgetEstimates be ON be.id = e.ContractID  
   AND be.Aur_ApprovedOn is not null  
   LEFT OUTER JOIN [LIBRARYBudgetEstimateType] ON [LIBRARYBudgetEstimateType].[BudgetEstimateTypeID] = be.[BudgetEstimateType] 
   AND  LIBRARYBudgetEstimateType.BudgetEstimateTypeName='Level 1' 
   JOIN WorkflowFormMapping W ON W.FormInstanceID = E.QPID  
    AND FormID = 'XQTYPLN'  
    AND w.CurrentStatus NOT IN ('Draft')   
) as a
where rn = 1 

--these variables are to to get forecast data for specific months
declare @startmonthnumber int,@todaymonthno int;

SELECT @StartMonthNumber = Number FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(INT, MonthNo) AS Number  
       ,SUBSTRING(TRIM([MonthName]),len(TRIM([MonthName]))-3,4) as [Year]
       ,SUBSTRING(TRIM([MonthName]),0,4) as [Month]
        FROM QTYPLANCalendar) AS A
        WHERE Year = @fy-1 and Month= 'Oct'

select @todaymonthno = MonthNo from QTYPLANCalendar where CAST(date AS DATE)=CAST(getdate() as DATE)

--PART : 2
--For each PID-forecastID/QPID pair that I have from the above #pidQpidlist I fetch the forecast details, for specific months
--The output of this table will have 3 records for each project, one record for one type each 'Board Approved Plan','Current Plan','Forecast'
--But here is there a way I can get all data in one row ? Will attach a screenshot for better understanding 
SELECT
CAST(SUM( CASE WHEN l.type='Board Approved Plan' AND sd.ScheduleID > @StartMonthNumber-1 AND sd.ScheduleID < @startmonthnumber+12 THEN sd.Quantity END) as numeric(18,2))  fyBoardPlanned,
 CAST(SUM( CASE WHEN l.type='Current Plan' AND sd.ScheduleID > @StartMonthNumber-1 AND sd.ScheduleID < @startmonthnumber+12 THEN sd.Quantity END) as numeric(18,2))  fyPlanned,
 CAST(SUM( CASE WHEN l.type='Forecast' AND sd.ScheduleID > @StartMonthNumber-1 AND sd.ScheduleID < @todaymonthno THEN sd.Quantity END) as numeric(18,2))  fyActuals,
  CAST(SUM( CASE WHEN l.type='Forecast' AND sd.ScheduleID > @todaymonthno-1 AND sd.ScheduleID < @startmonthnumber+12  THEN sd.Quantity END) as numeric(18,2))  fyRemForecast,
 l.ProjectID, l.type
into #forecastlevel1
FROM QTYPLANItemScheduleData sd
        JOIN CORITEMItemDetails bd with(nolock) ON sd.ItemID=bd.ItemID
join QTYPLANMaster q with(nolock) on q.QPID=sd.QPID 
inner join #pidQpidList l on q.ProjectId=l.ProjectID and sd.QPID=l.qpid
        GROUP BY l.ProjectID, l.ProjectCode, l.type

--PART : 3 
--fetch earliest L1 history Budget Estimate Record for each project
;with earliestL1History as (
select PID,TotalAmount from (SELECT  BE.PID, BE.EstimateTotal TotalAmount,ROW_NUMBER( ) over (partition by BE.pid order by wf.date) rn
FROM BDGTESTBudgetEstimates BE 
 JOIN WorkflowFormMapping WF ON BE.ID = WF.FormInstanceID and FormID='BDGTEST'
where WF.CurrentStatus='Level 1 History' 
) as a
where rn=1)

--PART : 4
--fetch latest L1 approved Budget Estimate Record for each project
,latestL1ApprovedRecord as (
select PID,TotalAmount from (SELECT  BE.PID, BE.EstimateTotal TotalAmount,ROW_NUMBER( ) over (partition by BE.pid order by wf.date desc) rn
FROM BDGTESTBudgetEstimates BE 
 JOIN WorkflowFormMapping WF ON BE.ID = WF.FormInstanceID and FormID='BDGTEST'
where WF.CurrentStatus='Level 1 Approved' 
) as a
where rn=1)

/*
    Note : only difference between Part 3 and 4 is that the Current status, and order by wf.date. Can this be reduced to be included in one query ?
*/

--PART : 5
--fetch sum of all approved expenses for each project
,approvedExpenses as(
SELECT  Ex.PID, SUM(Ex.TotCost) TotalAmount
FROM vw_AMTRAK_EXPSFRMExpenseList Ex 
 JOIN WorkflowFormMapping WF ON Ex.EFID = WF.FormInstanceID and FormID='EXPSFRM'
where WF.CurrentStatus='Approved' 
group by Ex.PID)

--PART : 6
--Main select statement , get all the data from all the above parts joinin evertyhing based on ProjectID.

select PM.ProjectId,PM.ProjectCode,PM.ProjectName
,(CASE WHEN BEhis.TotalAmount IS NULL
 THEN BEapp.TotalAmount ELSE BEhis.TotalAmount END)  LOPBoardPlanned
,BEapp.TotalAmount  LOPPlanned
,Ex.TotalAmount  LOPActuals
,(CASE WHEN (BEapp.TotalAmount IS NULL AND Ex.TotalAmount IS NULL)
 THEN NULL ELSE (ISNULL(BEapp.TotalAmount,0.00)-ISNULL(Ex.TotalAmount,0.00)) END) LOPRemainingCost
,(CASE WHEN BEapp.TotalAmount IS NULL THEN NULL
WHEN (BEhis.TotalAmount IS NULL AND ISNULL(BEapp.TotalAmount,0.00)=0) OR (BEhis.TotalAmount=0) THEN NULL 
WHEN BEhis.TotalAmount IS NULL THEN 0.00
ELSE BEapp.TotalAmount-BEhis.TotalAmount END) LOPBudgetVariance
,frBA.fyBoardPlanned FYBoardPlanned
,frCP.fyPlanned FYPlanned
,frF.fyActuals FYActuals
,frF.fyRemForecast FYRemainingForecast
,(ISNULL(frCP.fyPlanned,0.00)-(ISNULL(frF.fyActuals,0.00)+ISNULL(frF.fyRemForecast,0.00))) FYBudgetVariance

from (select DISTINCT ProjectID,ProjectCode,ProjectName from #pidQpidList) PM 
left join earliestL1History BEhis on BEhis.PID=PM.ProjectId
left join latestL1ApprovedRecord BEapp on BEapp.PID=PM.ProjectId
left join approvedExpenses ex on ex.PID=PM.ProjectId
left join #forecastlevel1 frBA on frBA.type='Board Approved Plan' and frBA.ProjectId=PM.ProjectId
left join #forecastlevel1 frCP on frCP.ProjectId=PM.ProjectId and frCP.type='Current Plan'
left join #forecastlevel1 frF on frF.ProjectId=PM.ProjectId and frF.type='Forecast'

drop table #pidQpidList, #forecastlevel1

END
```

Output of part 2 for each project

[image]

Note that in the output I fetch data for different types in separate rows, so for eg; fyBoardPlanned is for only type='Board Approved Plan' so the other two rows for fyBoardPlanned will be null.

Can this part be optimised ?

I have tried to optimise it, but I see the report still takes hefty amount of time to load.

PS: the number of projects is nearly 25k. I am tensed.

Please help me out, what I am missing, what all query parts can be reduced?

Comment: With respect, it's difficult to help you optimize such a large stored procedure. Ordinarily, [tag:query-optimization] work is done on a query-by-query basis. If you can isolate a query that's too slow, run it in SSMS, and show us the Actual Execution Plan, we may be able to offer specific advice. Paste the XML of the plan here. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Maybe create temp tables instead of using all those StringSplits? The ISNULLs aren't helping performance either.